# Javascript/JQuery: innerHTML Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to change the content inside `<div id="homePagePosts">` to be the new data from the server. The new data is in `HTML` format rendered by the server. However, the old HTML still stays the same after the `AJAX` data has been received by the browser.

When I `console.log` as shown below, I can see the rendered new HTML data is shown in the console. I have placed both Javascript and JQuery file at the bottom of the `<body>` but still doesn't work. I'm not too sure where it goes wrong here.

**HTML**

```
<div id="homePagePosts">
    <% include ../ajaxSnippets/mainHome %>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/main/home",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
  }).done(function(result){
      //This shows up in the console
      console.log(result)
      updateMainPagePosts(result);
  }).fail(function(err){
      console.log(err);
  });

var updateMainPagePosts = function(posts){
  document.getElementById("homePagePosts").innerHTML = posts;
};
```

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? What do you see when you use the debugger built into your browser to step through the code statement by statement? (E.g., set a breakpoint on the `console.log(results)`, look at `results`, step into `updateMainPagePosts`, look at what happens, etc.) Are you sure you don't have *two* elements with that `id`? (Only the first would be updated.) Fundamentally, if you have an element with `id="homePagePosts"` in your document, the code `document.getElementById("homePagePosts").innerHTML = posts;` (with `posts` being a parameter as shown) **will** update it.

Comment: Just wrap the whole JS above inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); It should work after that.

Comment: @LukeP.Issac: No, there's no need for that at all.

Comment: [***The code as shown works***](https://jsfiddle.net/ex82L2hm/). Until or unless the OP can provide more details, there's no point trying to answer this question. Steven, you've said you see `result` logged with the expected content (so the ajax call works). I'm afraid we can't help you further as the code from that point (calling `updateMainPagePosts` and the code within it) is correct. Debugging is the only way you'll find out what's happening. (It's also the first thing to do anyway. :-) ) Good luck!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very active place. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes to answer requests for more information, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your answer. Yup, you are right. I found that it's not something wrong with the AJAX code. Instead, it's because (I think) MongoDB is still saving the data when the server returns the response, thus it is shown as if nothing has happened on the browser (where in fact the server actually returns the data - just that it's the same data as before since MongoDB doesn't have enough time to update it).

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the function as a variable and is not usable in this method.

change this :

```
var updateMainPagePosts = function(posts){
  document.getElementById("homePagePosts").innerHTML = posts;
};
```

to this :

```
function updateMainPagePosts(posts){
  document.getElementById("homePagePosts").innerHTML = posts;
}
```

More details from: https://www.quora.com/Is-the-var-x-function-the-same-as-the-function-x-in-JavaScript:

> This will break. It uses a Function Expression which is being assigned
>   to a variable. console.log(myFunction(1, 2));   var myFunction =
>   function (a, b) {   return a + b; };
>
> This will print '3' to your console. It uses a Function Declaration.
>   console.log(myFunction(1, 2));   function myFunction(a, b) {   return
>   a + b; }
>
> The difference is that in the example with a function Definition, the
>   function is being "hoisted" to the start of the scope (which could be
>   a parent function, or the file, for example) by the JavaScript
>   interpreter, which means anywhere within that scope it can be called
>   and it will execute the function you have written.
>
> In the function Expression the function is being passed around as if
>   it were a value and is interpreted whenever it is asked to be. In the
>   example we're seeing here, it, as a value is being assigned to the
>   myFunction variable. Since we put a 'var' statement in front of that
>   variable, then myFunction that variable is being hoisted, but its
>   value, the function expression, is not hoisted (do not get the two
>   confused).